# Как красиво заанимировать эффект подпрыгивающей бутылки на CSS?

Tags: css3, анимация, css-animation

Как красиво заанимировать эффект подпрыгивающей бутылки ?

```js
$(".bottle").on("click", function() {

  $(this).addClass("bottle_animation");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".bottle").removeClass("bottle_animation")
  }, 2500);
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}

.field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bottle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 54px;
  height: 94px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.bottle_animation {
  animation: hinge 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
}

@keyframes hinge {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  20%,
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 80deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 80deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  40%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 700px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 700px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <div class="bottle"></div>
</div>
```

ищу способ на CSS. Чтобы было похоже, как при попадании по бутылки в тире.

Comment: пример бы какой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже на попадание по бутылке в тире?

```js
let field = document.querySelector('.field');
let rnd = (n, s) => (Math.random()*n + s || 0) + '% ';
let pt = (a, d, sep) => `${50 + Math.cos(a)*d}%${sep||' '}${50 + Math.sin(a)*d}%`;

let jump = e => {
    let el = e.target;
    el.classList.add('jump')
    setTimeout(e => el.classList.remove('jump'), 2500); 
}

let explode = e => {
    let el = e.target, angle = 0, node = el.outerHTML, nodes = '',
        center = 'polygon(' + rnd(30, 40) + rnd(30, 40) + ',';
    while (angle < Math.PI*2) {
      let dir = angle;
      let clip = center + pt(angle, 100) + ',';
      dir = (dir+(angle += Math.random()))/2;
      clip += pt(angle, 100) + ');';
      let tr = `translate(${pt(dir, 1000, ',')})rotate(${Math.random()*180}deg)`;
      let id = dir.toString(36).substring(2);
      nodes += node.split(' cl').join(` id="piece${id}" style="clip-path:${clip}" cl`);
      setTimeout(e => document.querySelector('#piece' + id).style.transform = tr);
      setTimeout(e => document.querySelector('#piece' + id).remove(), 1000); 
    }
    field.innerHTML = nodes;
    setTimeout(e => bottle(field.innerHTML = node), 1100); 
}

let bottle = e => document.querySelector('.bottle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  Math.random() > 0.5 ? explode(e) : jump(e);
});



bottle();
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bottle.jump {
  animation: 2s jumpUp linear forwards;
}

@keyframes jumpUp {
  0%{transform: translate(-50%, -50%)}
  30%{transform: translate(-30%, -180%)rotate(600deg)}
  35%{transform: translate(-20%, -200%)rotate(720deg)}
  100%{transform: translate(0%, 100%)rotate(1890deg)}
}


.bottle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 54px;
  height: 94px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1.5s;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="bottle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, она не подпрыгивает о_0

Comment: @Kromster ну да, пока в вопросе нет уточнений как подпрыгивает бутылка в тире, в моем тире она подпрыгивает по всему садоводству :), я художник, я так вижу. :)

Comment: Это замечательно! Но тогда возникает коллизия - ТС и те кто вопрос найдут по его текстовому описанию, будут ожидать "прыжки в высоту", а в ответе будет "rapid unscheduled disassembly" ;-)

Comment: Интересно было бы увидеть эффект когда бутылка подлетает вверх, делает кувырок и падаем вниз. (Возможно по второму попаданию, как раз и разлетается)  Что, то похожее на (http://vseigru.net/igry-na-lovkost/24544-igra-strelba-po-butylkam.html)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вот это уже похоже на нормальное описание эффекта, скоро попробую :)

Comment: @Kromster а я ни на что не претендую, зато остальная семантика соблюдена, кроме подпрыгивания, и те кто будут искать про тир, я надеюсь, порадуются

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вносите все уточнения в вопрос - кнопка "править"

Comment: @BlackStar1991 в этой игре бутылки при попадании явно не подпрыгивают, а делают что-то похожее на то что я вчера соорудил

Comment: @BlackStar1991 теперь с вероятностью 50% бутылка подпрыгивает

Answer (score 1):

Попытка на css - не знаю как доделать

В общем событие `:focus`

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.con {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  transform: translateY(300px);
}

.img-con {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-con img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-con:nth-of-type(2) img {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: 0.1s;
}

label:focus {
  transform: scale(0.3)translateX(-150%)rotateX(200deg)rotateY(20deg);
}

label:focus .img-con:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-30deg)scale(0.4);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

label:focus .img-con:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(30deg)scale(0.4);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <label tabindex="-1">
      <div class="img-con">
          <img src="https://unitedbottles.com/app/uploads/United-bottles-Packaging-bouteille-vertes-wn062.png" alt="" class="btl">
    </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://unitedbottles.com/app/uploads/United-bottles-Packaging-bouteille-vertes-wn062.png" alt="" class="btl">
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```